# Python 3.4: zlib, deflate and shared dict

Tags: python, zlib

Any ideas how to fix following code (Python 3.4.3):

```
import zlib


hello = b'hello'

co = zlib.compressobj(wbits=-zlib.MAX_WBITS, zdict=hello)
data = co.compress(hello) + co.flush()

do = zlib.decompressobj(wbits=-zlib.MAX_WBITS, zdict=hello)
data = do.decompress(data)

print(data)
```

Fails for me with

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

What I am trying to do is to decompress deflate that was compressed with shared dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use negative wbits with a dictionary. Negative wbits gets rid of the zlib header and trailer, but the zlib header is how decompress knows to use a dictionary.

Just get rid of the wbits options.

Comment: I need to "decompress deflate that was compressed with shared dictionary". If I get rid of wbits zlib will fail because I don't have zlib header and trailer.

Comment: What are you quoting? Can you provide a link?

Comment: I am quoting my question. If you are asking how I get deflate with shared dictionary then I am using Go - https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/#NewWriterDict

Comment: I answered your question, which was "how to fix following code". Apparently that is not really your question. Why is it that "I don't have zlib header and trailer"? What is the source of the data?

Comment: Deleting the code also fixes it. I already provided all info:
- my question contains "What I am trying to do is to decompress deflate that was compressed with shared dictionary.".
- my previous comment says that I am using https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/#NewWriterDict to compress some data.

Comment: You will need to insert a zlib header that requests a dictionary, and that has the Adler-32 check value of the dictionary, before the raw deflate data. See RFC 1950.